# Get the window handle of the Windows setup process

Tags: c#, process

I am trying to automate Windows 10 installation by first mounting the .iso file on the drive. And then using c# to start windows 10 installation by using this below code which passes the keys to the installation application

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);
public static void Main(String[] args){
    Process p1 = Process.Start("h:\\setup.exe");
    IntPtr h = p1.MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(h);
    Thread.Sleep(30000);
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
}
```

But the problem is that the setup window is not taking the signal of the ENTER key in the code. The setup window is starting with this code. After that, nothing is happening.

```
Process p1 = Process.Start("h:\\setup.exe");
```

I tried using notepad instead of setup.exe in the code which is taking all the ENTER keys. Please tell me if anyone has a solution. Thank you

Comment: There are far easier ways to automate a Windows installation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/automate-windows-setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disclaimer:

> I would advise against automating a Windows setup using something like
>   `SendKeys` as you can't guarantee a consistent behavior and could
>   easily mess things up. You may consider looking for different
>   approaches [as suggested by lan Kemp in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155019/automating-windows-10-installation/55155112?noredirect=1#comment97050256_55155019). This answer
>   only shows you how to get the handle of the setup window correctly.
>   You may use it at your own risk.

### Update:

Apparently, the Windows 10 setup executable ("Setup.exe") starts another process called "SetupPrep.exe" which starts a third process called "SetupHost.exe" (the one you're after). So, what you can do is start the main process, wait for the target process to start *and* obtain a `MainWindowHandle` before executing the remaining code:

```
Process p1 = Process.Start("H:\\setup.exe");

Process targetProcess;
do
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    targetProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("SetupHost").FirstOrDefault();
} while (targetProcess == null || targetProcess.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero);

IntPtr h = targetProcess.MainWindowHandle;
// ...
```

This should solve your problem, however, it's not a wise idea to use `SendKeys` for this purpose. Please refer to the disclaimer above.

### Original answer:

Did you make sure that `h` does actually have a value *(other than `IntPtr.Zero`)*? Because it probably doesn't have the actual window handle since you don't give the process enough time to start and obtain a window handle.

Try something like this:

```
Process p1 = Process.Start("h:\\setup.exe");
while (p1.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}

IntPtr h = p1.MainWindowHandle;
// ...
```

Comment: @DKB "It's not working" is not a description of a problem. Describe what exactly happens when you run the code. What's the value of `h`? etc.

Comment: When I used your code it is not showing value as if it is in infinite loop. And when I remove your code then it is showing 0. I used Console.WriteLine() to print value of h on console.

Comment: @DKB Does the process actually start? And does the setup window show up?

Comment: It is working for notepad then why does it not working for setup window?

Comment: @DKB Edited the answer.

Comment: Still not working h is giving some value now but the setup window is not taking that value as if it is ignoring it. You are the only hope man tomorrow is my project submission on this topic I am in great trouble man I thought that it will work fine like notepad. And I can't use another method bcoz my project is like there is one server and other client. Where server sends iso file on client and client mount that file and start installing it. I used unattended.xml file like lan Kemp said in comment to automate process after the computer restarts but first we have to initiate process.

Comment: @DKB Make sure your application runs as administrator. The Windows setup process is an elevated process, therefore, `SendKeys` won't work unless your process is elevated as well.

Comment: It worked man it worked I have no word to Thank-you man you are great.

Comment: You can state in your answer to run the program as administrator